# Send email on edit - google sheets

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to send an email if a condition is meet; let's say if A1 is "OK" send email to email address on A2 with data of A3 and A4.

How can I do this?

Comment: `function onMyEdit(e){if(sheet.getRange('A1').getValue() == "OK") { GmailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange('A2').getValue(),'Subject',sheet.getRange('A3:A4').getValues()[0].join(','))}` I'd use an installable trigger.

Comment: Cooper, thanks for your reply!
I'm trying to run with some modifications, but no result:

function onMyEdit(e){
  var sheet = "teste";
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet);
  if(sourceSheet.getRange('A2').getValue() == "OK") { GmailApp.sendEmail(sheet.getRange('B2').getValue(),'Subject',sheet.getRange('C2:D2').getValues()[0].join(','))}

}

Comment: What action is required to send the email?

Comment: the "OK" on the cell will trigger it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take this opportunity to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how to [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13196995/daniel-h)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

I used a check box in column 5 to trigger it.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();  
  if (sh.getName() == 'teste' && sh.getRange('A2').getValue() == "OK" && e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1')
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    GmailApp.sendEmail(sh.getRange('B2').getValue(), 'Subject', sh.getRange('C2:D2').getValues()[0].join(','));
  }
}

function createMyTrigger1() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'onMyEdit').length==0) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('onMyEdit').forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
}
```

[image]

This version sends the email on OK in column 1

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  //e.source.toast('Entry');
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();  
  if (sh.getName() == 'teste' && sh.getRange('A2').getValue() == "OK" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value == "OK") {
    //e.source.toast('Flag1')
    e.range.setValue("FALSE");
    GmailApp.sendEmail(sh.getRange('B2').getValue(), 'Subject', sh.getRange('C2:D2').getValues()[0].join(','));
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Comment: You can not run these type of functions from the script editor.  Just save it and create the trigger and go edit sheet teste in either colum 1 or column 5 on row 2 depending upon which version you are using. The function needs the event objecct from the onedit trigger which occours on every user edit of any cell in the spreadsheet. I tested them...they work.